# Lost all stickies in OSX

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to recover deleted text inside Mac OS X sticky notes.](https://superuser.com/questions/243087/how-to-recover-deleted-text-inside-mac-os-x-sticky-notes)

I had a lot of stickies with a lot of information. I clicked on stickies to open them up, and a blank sticky appeared. All the stickies are gone. How could this have happened? Is there a way to get them back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stickies live in `~/Library/StickiesDatabase`.  Worse come to worst, I hope you have a backup.  If it's corrupted, there's a slight chance you can get things back out of it with `strings` in a Terminal window.

Comment: The file is 4 kb. Strings only shows a few things like streamtyped, NSMutableArray, NSArray. Does this look empty?

Comment: Effectively, yes; you're seeing the scaffolding around a NeXT/OS X typed stream, but no content.

Comment: What could have caused this?

Comment: My best guess is that Stickies crashed for some reason while trying to update its database, and the resulting corruption caused the next startup to zero it out.