# How is the data for Dashboard Stickies stored?

Tags: macos

I want to restore the files containing Dashboard Stickies data from a backup drive. In which files is this information stored, and how can I read it on computers without Mac OS X?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All data for Dashboard Stickies is stored in the file `/Users/username/Library/Preferences/widget-com.apple.widget.stickies.plist`.

It's a binary property list file, but the relevant parts (Stickies text in HTML format) can be read in most plain text editors.

Comment: Thank you very much, do you know also where are saved stickers not from the dashboard, but from the applications directory (there is different kind of sticker in applications directory)?

Comment: I observed very little part is saved as html, the part which I want to restore is not saved as HTML.

Comment: @Newbie1 http://superuser.com/questions/243087/how-to-recover-deleted-text-inside-mac-os-x-sticky-notes

Comment: Thank you, so it is in `/Users/username/Library/StickiesDatabase` and the content is readable in text editor. Thank you again.

Comment: F?or the regular stickies app, which is NOT the OP's question, it's `~/Library/StickiesDatabase`